# Как использовать многоцветный SVG в качестве маски?

Tags: javascript, html5, svg

Я знаю, как использовать маски SVG, чтобы полностью «вырезать» маску другой формы, если маска монохромная.
Как я могу использовать многоцветное определение `X` SVG в качестве маски, чтобы внешняя форма `X` определяла `дыру`, которую нужно вырезать?

Вот три изображения, которые иллюстрируют то, что я пытаюсь достичь:

1. *Первое изображение*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. *Второе изображение*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. *Результат*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли другой, более простой способ добиться того, чего я хочу?

Comment: @ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53720773/7394871:

Answer (score 3):

Вы должны определить свои пути без заливки. Затем вы используете свои пути для маски и заполните их белым цветом. Чтобы нарисовать изображение, вы заполняете эти пути выбранными вами цветами.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:49vw}
svg:nth-child(2){background:red;}
mask use{fill:white;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <defs>
   <polygon id="a"  points="30,5 70,20 75,40 20,20" />
   <circle id="b" cx="50" cy="25" r="15" />
   <circle id="c" cx="60" cy="35" r="10" />
   <mask id="m">
   <use xlink:href="#a"/>
   <use xlink:href="#b"/>
   <use xlink:href="#c"/>
   </mask>

  </defs>
  <g id="complexShape">
  <use xlink:href="#a" fill="lightblue" />
  <use xlink:href="#b" fill="gold"/>
  <use xlink:href="#c" fill="red"/>
  </g>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <rect width="100" height="50" style="mask: url(#m)" />
</svg>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53722728/7394871) @enxaneta

Answer (score 2):

Цвет маски определяет окончательную непрозрачность маскируемого объекта в этой точке.

Компоненты **R**, **G**, **B** цвета маски и **A** -альфа канал,   объединяются в формулу для определения значения яркости, которое используется для установки конечной прозрачности.
Так, например, если маска красная, конечный результат маскирования будет полупрозрачным.

Невозможно сделать цветной объект сплошной (не полупрозрачной) маской. Только полный белый сделает это.

Предполагая, что у вас есть внешнее изображение SVG, которое выглядит следующим образом:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
 <polygon id="a"  points="30,5 70,20 75,40 20,20" fill="lightblue"/>
 <circle id="b" cx="50" cy="25" r="15" fill="gold"/>
 <circle id="c" cx="60" cy="35" r="10" fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>
```

Вы можете превратить это в «маску», добавив три строки в начало вашего SVG.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
 <filter id="blacken"><feFlood flood-color="black"/><feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/></filter>
 <style>svg :not(#maskbg) { filter: url(#blacken); }</style>
 <rect id="maskbg" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%" fill="white"/>
 <polygon id="a"  points="30,5 70,20 75,40 20,20" fill="lightblue"/>
 <circle id="b" cx="50" cy="25" r="15" fill="gold"/>
 <circle id="c" cx="60" cy="35" r="10" fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>
```

После того, как вы создали все варианты маски, вы можете применить их, используя `mask-image`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

[Источник ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53721081/7394871)а @Paul LeBeau